# Apache2 reverse proxy to a nextcloud server does not work

Tags: apache, webserver, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I've made a Ubuntu 18.04 Reverse Proxy Server with Apache2 and it works. I can reverse proxy to another apache2 webserver with no problem.

But now I want to do the exact same thing to a nextcloud server but it does not work.

**My steps:**

1) I copied the old configuration
2) changed the external Domain and the internal IP Adress from the Server
3) now I restarted the apache2 server and it does not work

[image: Nextcloud Reverse Proxy Configuration]

*There is no error in the error.log file from apache.*

Maybe there is an error on the nextcloud server but I don't know how to continue.

Thanks Raphael

Comment: What does "does not work" exactly mean, what can you see in your browser?

Comment: Hey, the error was: "The website cannot be reached" however I deinstalled Apache and tried the same thing (reverse proxy) with nginx and it worked out excactly how I wanted it. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my working config for the Apache proxy pointing to the local Nextcloud in a Docker based instance:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName cloud.myserver.local
ServerAlias cloud
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```